# Google Youtube Data v3 not found

Tags: api, youtube-api, key

I have gone through a tutorial that takes me to the console.developers.google.com/ webpage.  I created a new project, then i went to API & Auth .. clicked on the API key to try to then scroll down and select the Youtube Data API v3 and it is NOT there, why?  I need to get the API key for an application I am using. I have logged in to two separate accounts and it is not available in either account.  I need help in finding the API key so that I can use it in an application. I called the adwords team and asked them and they asked me to send a question to you in this forum.

Comment: This is most likely a very ridiculous question (and not meant to be condescending at all), but sometimes it's helpful to first just eliminate the obvious; is there any chance you've already enabled it? The list of enabled APIs is always at the very top, rather than staying in alphabetical order.

Comment: It's not at all a ridiculous question, I am having the exact same issue and am absolutely positive the Youtube Data API is not an option on the list of APIs, enabled or not.

Answer (score 0):

By default, there were a few Google Cloud APIs enabled by default. When they were enabled, the Youtube Data API was not showing up in the list of available APIs. I disabled all the preselected APIs, and then the Youtube Data and Analytics APIs were available.
Looks like you just have to disable the default selections for some reason.